# How do I encode the names of Microsoft group and teams names to include them in an API call URL?

Tags: ms-office, office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

If I have an Office 365 Group/Microsoft Team with the ID "testteam@example.onmicrosoft.com", and I want to query it using one of the beta APIs such as [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_list_threads) one, I need to query a URL such as `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/threads`. However, I am stuck on encoding the team name. `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/testteam@example.onmicrosoft.com/threads`, `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/testteam@example%2Eonmicrosoft%2E/threads`, and `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/testteam@example/threads`, `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/"testteam@example"/threads,` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/"testteam@example.onmicrosoft.com"/threads` all return the following error

```
"error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid object identifier 'whatever_I_entered'."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it's just regular URL Encode. For example in JS you may use function `encodeURIComponent(str)`. If you want to try use [online URL encoder](https://www.urlencoder.org/). For example encoded version of `testteam@example.onmicrosoft.com` will looks like `testteam%40example.onmicrosoft.com` and your graph request would be `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/testteam%40example.onmicrosoft.com/threads`

EDIT:

In the request you need to use **Id** of the group. For example: [Get Group](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_get) request may looks like ... and the group id is `c28c1cc9-e1ab-4c4d-98d1-d8fdf128b60f`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1,0/groups/c28c1cc9-e1ab-4c4d-98d1-d8fdf128b60f?$select=description,allowExternalSenders
```

Comment: Can you run request to retrieve list of your available groups? [List Groups](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list). Do you see requested group id in the list? By the way you need to use **Id**!

Comment: Thank you, that was it! In the Office365 admin panel the names@email format is labelled Group ID, but the List Groups API you linked to returns the correct values.

Comment: @stackquestions23 Glad it helped ;)